# update uilabels when application becomes active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to do something very simple: update a few labels on my (one and only) view controller when the application becomes active after coming from the background (say with the current time for the simplicity of it (even though in my case, I am updating telephony parameters, such as call states, etc., but that should not matter)).

Honestly, I was sure that once I call `viewDidLoad`, the code in this method runs again and so all my labels will be up to date. But that doesnt happen, unless I kill the app and relaunch it, so what I did in the app delegate under `applicationDidBecomeActive`, I called my view controller method:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc refreshCalls];
```

Which does execute this code, but nothing happens to the labels. When doing this, I am also showing an `UIAlertView` that DOES have the updated info on it, but not the labels.

How can I fix this? Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Here is my app delegate applicationDidBecomeActive method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc refreshCalls];
}
```

And the `refreshCalls` method in the view controller:

```
 -(void) refreshCalls {

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);

  UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TIME" message:currentTime delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];

 [alert1 show]; --> does show an update time        

myLabel.text = currentTime;
[self.view addSubview:myLabel]; --> nothing happens, stays the last time

 }
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your viewController, try self.viewcontroller

Comment: not sure i understand this...where should I do the self.viewcontroller? and how come the AlertView does get updated correctly when i can the refresh method? thanks.

Comment: instead of `alloc init` you do `ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.viewController;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call `ViewDidLoad`. It gets called for you, just like `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Now, to the answer:

What is happening is that you are calling your `refreshCalls` method on a new `ViewController` instead of your existing one, which you probably created somewhere in your app delegate. When you first created your `ViewController`, you probably added its view to `UIWindow`.

Then, when you create a new `ViewController` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and call `refreshCalls` on it, it gets updated just like it should, but its view is not shown on the screen, because you didn't add it to `UIWindow`.

Try to locate in your `appDelegate` where do you first create your `ViewController` and assign it to a property. Then, instead of creating a new `ViewController` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, get your existing one and call your `refreshCalls` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you already have a `myLabel` in your view, you probably shouldn't add another one. Maybe you can try to have a `@property` like `self.myLabel`, and just call `self.myLabel.text = currentTime;` everytime you want to update its text. (without `addSubview` again or stuff..)

Comment: doesnt work. moved the addSubview to the viewDidLoad method, and added self.myLabel like you mentioned. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You could update your labels in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidAppear:animated` instead of using `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self refreshCalls];
}
```

Comment: I thought that that should work, but from some odd reason, the viewDidAppear: is not getting called when I tap on the app from the background and bring it to the foreground. applicationDidBecomeActive: is called, but not viewDidAppear: of my viewcontroller. any thoughts?

Comment: Yes you are right! This also affected one of my projects, so I came out with more generic solution to make sure view controllers which need to know about applicationDidBecomeActive and similar UIApplicationDelegate events, register for them and get notified. If you are interested, I can post it here.

Comment: Yes, please do, that sounds like something that I'd use a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to create another answer as a result of my previous one in order to avoid confusion.

The basic idea is to keep a list of subscribers in your `UIApplication` class and notify them when `UIApplicationDelegate` events are received. Here is how to do it.

Step 1

In your `UIApplication` derived class header add definitions of static methods to manage the list:

```
+ (void)addDelegate:(id <UIApplicationDelegate>)delegate;
+ (void)removeDelegate:(id <UIApplicationDelegate>)delegate;
```

I'm using `UIApplicationDelegate` since it is a "natural" solution. However you could define your own protocol or extend `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Step 2

Add implemetation in your application class. First add definition for the list somewhere between last `#import` and `@implementation`.

```
static NSMutableArray *_delegates;
```

inside `@implementation` we add the static methods body and initialization:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    _delegates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

+ (void)addDelegate:(id <UIApplicationDelegate>)delegate {
    [_delegates addObject:delegate];
}

+ (void)removeDelegate:(id <UIApplicationDelegate>)delegate {
    [_delegates removeObject:delegate];
}
```

For each `UIApplicationDelegate` method you need to notify your subscribers about, add code similar to this sample:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [_delegates objectEnumerator];
    id delegate;

    while (delegate = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)]) {
            [delegate applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3

In your `UIViewController` (or any other class) add the code to subscribe, unsubscribe and handle notifications. Don't forget to import your `UIApplication` class header.

Subscription can be set inside your init method or for `UIViewController` inside `viewDidLoad` is good too.

```
[MyAppDelegate addDelegate:self]; // your class should implement UIApplicationDelegate
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe or bad things can happen! Add this in your dealloc method or for `UIViewController` inside `viewDidUnload` is fine.

```
[MyAppDelegate removeDelegate:self];
```

Finally add `UIApplicationDelegate` methods you need to get notified about ex:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // add your notification handling code here
}
```