# Best approach for implementing a pincode for application launch & didEnterForground

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have constructed a pincode view controller that I would like to implement in my app to secure it from unwanted fingers.

I have been looking into how best to implement it so it appears only when the app is first launched & when it returns to the foreground after being in the background.

The appDelegate.m has didFinishLoading & applicationWillEnterForeground but I have been unable to create my view controller here because the window has not yet been loaded.

I would add it to the viewDidLoad method of my view controller but I'm using a TabBarController so would need to do this for all tasks & then the pin would be required whenever the user switches between them.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ code examples/ best practices of how I can achieve this?

Many thanks, James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your AppDelegate's `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`. I believe you have a window at this point. Anyway even if there is no window yet, there are easy workarounds for that.

Comment: Hi Demonsten, when I add the code below to my applicationDidBecomeActive method 

    `PINAuthViewController *pinController = [[PINAuthViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pinController animated:YES completion:nil];`

the screen goes blank (black) and I get the following output in the console:
`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TBMasterViewController: 0x9e88620>.
Warning: Attempt to present <PINAuthViewController: 0xaa8f930> on <TBMasterViewController: 0x9e88620> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Hello James. I did a simple sample project just to check that this works. It does work. Tested in several configurations. The only possible problem I found up to this moment is, you have to check if there is no currently presenting modal view controller. In that case presentViewController has no effect. Please inspect your controllers chain and what your controllers need for proper setup. Probably there is some application specific reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Hi Demosten, I'm afraid I couldn't get this to work at all. Instead I have implemented the following: In appDelegate.m for methods such as `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` I am writing to NSUserDefaults a bool which is then checked in the view controllers viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear method. This works when the application is terminated however when it is suspended with the home button and then reopened viewWillAppear isn't called. Is there any method I can use in the view controller that will be called here? I have tried viewWillAppear&viewDidLoad. Thanks, James

Comment: Check out answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812542/update-uilabels-when-application-becomes-active/11822998 . The accepted answer could help you and the second answer is mine. It's something I use in one of my published apps.

Comment: Thanks Demosten! In the accepted answer, I'm not adding the view to the window at all, IB is handing this via the storyboard - so I'm not sure this is the issue. In relation to your answer I have one TabBarController with multiple tabs each with their own VC class. I guess I need to add all of these to the delegates Array? Another question, UIApplicationDelegate, is that a standard class provided? Because I cannot find it. Perhaps if you could provide a very simple project that I can take a look at to help me get my head round it? Thanks! James

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate is a protocol not class and your AppDeledate class implements it. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html . If you use my solution you might need to add this protocol implementation to as many as needed view controllers. However in your case I really think that you are missing something simple and you should go for the solution mentioned in your first comment here.

Comment: About providing whole samples. I believe you should fight your own battles. Here is a starting point. Make a simple sample with your setup in a new project (Tab controller and Storyboard?). Don't add anything other. Add and new view as a PIN view controller. Set some button there to close it. In your `applicationDidBecomeActive` load your controller and show it with code like `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pinController animated:YES completion:nil];`. When you make it work translate your solution to your real complex project and make it work there. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the help Demonsten. Using the provided answer on the link I have been able to implement it successfully. In the end I used a combination of the methods in appDelegate.m & adding an observer to the code for the applicationDidBecomeActive method. 
    `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkPINCodeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];`